# The meaning of this expression 視線をそわそわと泳がせる (Describing someone's eyes/ the way they're looking at you )

Tags: grammar, meaning, expressions, reading-comprehension, japanese-to-english

**Can someone explain to me this expression ? 視線をそわそわと泳がせる .**

**I met this part when MC is complimenting a girl that she's very cute. (I can only understand that her gaze/ eyes did not looking straight at MC). This describing a girl's eyes/ gaze.**

More context:

MC「ヒカリって本当に可愛い」

ヒカリ「っ……」

最初に褒めたときと同じく、言葉を詰まらせ、**視線をそわそわと泳がせる。**

Answer (score 2):

泳ぐ has [various figurative meanings](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%B3%B3%E3%81%90), one of which is "to totter". 目が泳ぐ (also 視線が泳ぐ) is a common set phrase that describes one's eyes being shifty (due to embarrassment, anxiety, a sense of guilt, etc.). 視線を泳がせる is a causative form of it.